# Why don't most authentication gems, like Devise, encrypt email (i.e. PII information) out of the box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, encryption, devise

To my understanding, 'email' is often considered personally identifiable information, but I very rarely see it encrypted in tutorials or gems. Devise, for instance, doesn't encrypt email or IP addresses out of the box.

Why aren't these fields encrypted more often given they can be considered PII? Encrypting email in Devise with attr_encrypted has proven to be very difficult. I'm wondering if there's something I'm just missing, like "oh, no, you don't have to encrypt those because...".

Not a critique I'm forever grateful to the open source devs for their work, just curious.

Comment: There are two kinds of PII: sensitive and non-sensitive. Only the sensitive has to be encrypted. And email is not sensitive PII. Where "sensitive" is defined as "it allows identifying an individual and, if becomes known to other parties, can be used to cause harm to that individual"

Comment: One could argue that email is not PII at all. Good luck pinning "sexy_kitten364657@gmail.com" to an individual. SSN, on the other hand...